# Split file into files with keyword in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to figure out how to take a file and divide in into sub-files using a keyword as the split indicator. In my case, I have a large file that looks like this:

`Racecar`
`line2...`
`line3...`
`Racecar`
`line5...`
`line6...`
`line7...`
`line8...`
`Racecar`
`line10...`

At each occurrence of the word `Racecar` I would like to split the file and make a subfile. Using the above example, File_1 would have 3 lines, File_2 would have 5 lines, and File_3 would have 2 lines. These files would look like this:

File_1:
`Racecar`
`line2...`
`line3...`

File_2:
`Racecar`
`line5...`
`line6...`
`line7...`
`line8...`

File_3:
`Racecar`
`line10...`

I realize something like sed or awk would be better suited for this, but I need to do this in Python. I'm really stuck on this for some reason. I tried to write something like this:

```
with open("bigfile", mode="r") as bigfile:
    reader = bigfile.readlines()
    for i,line in enumerate(reader):
        if line.startswith("Racecar"):
            header = line
            header_num = i
```

I seem to be getting stuck because I can't find a way to get the next occurrence of Racecar. I keep wanting to use the `next()` function, but obviously this doesn't work on strings. The file I am using is small enough to be read into memory. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: On QNX You don't need Python for that ;). [QNX's split can split file when regexp/pattern is found](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.5.0/topic/com.qnx.doc.neutrino_utilities/s/split.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
with open("bigfile", mode="r") as bigfile:
    reader = bigfile.read()
    for i,part in enumerate(reader.split("Racecar")):
        with open("File_" + i+1, mode="w") as newfile:
            newfile.write("Racecar"+part)
```

Comment: `readlines` returns a list, and you're calling split on it which doesn't exist.

Comment: @Vader, reading a list of lines and then joining seems wasteful. How about just `bigfile.read()`?

Comment: +1 then :). (BTW, Whoever downvoted this should explain why.)

Comment: Thanks everyone! The above code worked great. The only issue I have is that I get one extra file that just contains `Racecar`.

Comment: @dr.bunsen This happened because 'Racecar' is the first word in the source file therefore the first part of `reader.split("Racecar")` is an empty string. I think that `reader.split("Racecar")[1:]` instead of `reader.split("Racecar")` in the code above should solve your issue.

Comment: Or `if part:`. Also, this can quite easily be done without reading the whole file into memory, although that's probably never a problem with a text file.

Comment: @Vader thanks for the followup. Indeed `reader.split("Racecar")[1:]` did the trick. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

```
out_array = []
with open("bigfile", mode="r") as bigfile:
    for line in bigfile:
        if line.startswith("Racecar"):
            out_array.append(line)
        else:
            out_array[-1] += line

for i in range(len(out_array)):
    out_filename = "File%d.txt" % i
    with open(out_filename, mode="w") as out_file:
         out_file.write(out_array[i]);
```

There are probably more efficient ways, particularly of avoiding two loops. However if it's as small as you claim it shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you've found a way to get the next occurrence of Racecar. Your `for` loop will reach all of them eventually. The question is what to do when you reach them. I don't understand what you're going for with `header`, `header_num`, etc.

Seems like the thing to do is to iterate over the lines in bigfile as you do (though without the redundant `readlines`), and every time you hit a `Racecar` line, open a new output file.

As in:

```
with open("bigfile", mode="r") as bigfile:
    smallfile_prefix = "File_"
    file_count = 0
    smallfile = open(smallfile_prefix + str(file_count), 'w')
    for line in bigfile:
        if line.startswith("Racecar"):
            smallfile.close()
            file_count += 1
            smallfile = open(smallfile_prefix + str(file_count), 'w')
        else:
            smallfile.write(line)
    smallfile.close()
```

There are other ways to do this -- some variation on [Vader's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6959558/split-file-into-files-with-keyword-in-python/6959682#6959682) is probably better, for example -- but this seems closest to your original approach.